# Updating SSL 3.0 to TLS guidance

Tags: ssl, paypal, poodle-attack

I have received the email about the poodle SSL 3.0 situation that has come about. Like everyone else, I really want to tackle this before the December 3rd deadline rolls around. I've been trying to follow the how to update from SSL 3.0 to TLS since PayPal said it's so easy which may be true for most but for me it's a bit overwhelming. Here I ask if someone has a really good walk through that I could take a look at to take care of this issue?? Or even throw in a the steps in here would be great too! I've tried contacting paypal but they are not providing me the guidance that I need.

I appreciate it!!

Comment: Can you please provide some background on what you are using ? What language you are using ? Is it PHP ? 

You could get some detailed information about this here : https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1182

Also, it would help if you could let us know what particular SDK you are using ?

Comment: You just need to make sure your API requests (probably through cURL) are not using SSLv3, which will typically only be happening if you've hard-coded that option into your cURL setup one way or another.  The recommended procedure is to let cURL utilize its default fallback system, which will it will do as long as you're not specifying a protocol in the cURL options...and as long as you're not running cURL or OpenSSL versions from 15+ years ago.

Comment: Thank you for your input, your feedback has me feeling a lot better about the situation. I did a little more research as well and we're in the clear, thanks again @AndrewAngell